# How do prevent blanks from being created while using nested forms and rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have a nested form question.erb that displays the pre written question (:poll) and then has text_fields (:response) for the answers. The problem that I am running into is that blank questions are being created in the database. I have done a fair bit of research on the issue and it appears that the answer would be adding

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['poll'].blank? }
```

to the event model. The issue with this is of course is now I am preventing everything from being written. How would I go about only writing the answers to the database and ignoring (or not creating at all) the blank questions? Please let me know if any of the other files might be needed for the solution.

Thanks!

question.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@event) do |f| %>
     <%= f.error_notification %>
     <%= f.object.name %>
     <%= f.simple_fields_for :questions, @event.questions do |q| %>
        <%= q.object.poll%>
        <%= q.simple_fields_for :answers, q.object.answers.build do |a|%>
           <%= a.text_field :response %>
        <% end %>
     <% end %>
     <%= f.button :submit%>
<% end %>
```

event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :questions
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end
```

events_controller.rb (selected portions)

```
 def question
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
 end 

def update
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    if @event.update(event_params)
        redirect_to events_path, notice: "Answers saved"
     else
        redirect_to events_question_path, notice: "Answers not saved"
    end
end 

  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(
        questions_attributes: [:poll, answers_attributes: [:response]])
  end
```

question.rb

```
 class Question < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :event

 has_many :answers


 accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
 end
```

question_controller.rb

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
       @questions = Question.all
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
       @question = Question.new

    end


    def edit
    end

    def create
        @question = Question.new(question_params)

        @question.user = current_user

        respond_to do |format|
            if @question.save
                format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully created.' }
                format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @question }
            else
                format.html { render :new }
                format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

   def update
        @question.user = current_user.id
        respond_to do |format|
            if @question.update(question_params)
               format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully updated.' }
               format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @question }
            else
               format.html { render :edit }
               format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
   end

   # DELETE /questions/1
   # DELETE /questions/1.json
   def destroy
      @question.destroy
         respond_to do |format|
             format.html { redirect_to questions_url }
              format.json { head :no_content }
          end
       end

   private

   def set_question
        @question = Question.find(params[:id])
   end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def question_params
       params.require(:question).permit(:poll, :event_id, answer_attributes: [:response, :question, :event, :user, :event_id, :question_id, :user_id])
    end
 end
```

Comment: Can you post your params?

Comment: which params are you looking for? the params that are passed through on the action?

Comment: The ones when you make a new question or whatever. I'd like to see what data is being passed

Comment: @RichPeck  "event"=>{"questions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"event_id"=>"182", "answers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"response"=>"ss"}}, "id"=>"20"}, "1"=>{"event_id"=>"182", "answers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"response"=>"sss"}}, "id"=>"21"}}}, "commit"=>"Update Event", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"events", "id"=>"182"}

Comment: I think I need to figure out how to pass the question ID along so that rails realizes the question has already been created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just deleting a question with a blank :poll after the creation. question model is as follows

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
     belongs_to :event

     has_many :answers

     accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers

     after_save { |question| question.destroy if question.poll.blank? }
end
```

I'm sure theres a better way and will gladly accept better answers. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :questions
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, reject_if: :all_blank
end
```

You can read more about it on [the official docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for), but in a nutshell that will prevent any question that is completely blank from being saved, and let any populated question through.

Comment: that should be the solution, but somewhere my code is writing in the event_id for question thus making it not blank. So the solution now is to focus on another blank datapoint ie :poll or figure out how not make the event_id not get written. I'm going look at this in the morning. thanks for the help.

Comment: also if i reject the question I wont be able to write the answer to the DB.

Comment: Makes sense - looking at your solution, I realise I misunderstood the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
  validates_associated :questions
end
```

This should solve your problem, be careful though not to use this on the other side of your relation, as it will cause infinite loop.

I guess I should add that once you add the validates helper method to your model, you can do this:

```
e = Event.new
e.valid?
=>false
```

This may be of some help: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Try:

`@question = Question.create(question_params)`

instead of:

`@question = Question.new(question_params)`

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
end

>> p = Person.new
# => #<Person id: nil, name: nil>
>> p.errors.messages
# => {}

>> p.valid?
# => false
>> p.errors.messages
# => {name:["can't be blank"]}

>> p = Person.create
# => #<Person id: nil, name: nil>
>> p.errors.messages
# => {name:["can't be blank"]}

>> p.save
# => false

>> p.save!
# => ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name can't be blank

>> Person.create!
# => ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name can't be blank
```

Comment: just implemented this and the blanks are still being created :(. Would you like to see some other files? Thanks

Comment: You will still have to check, in your save method. This only allows you to check for .valid?

Comment: sorry just to clarify are you talking about the update method in the question?

Comment: I guess it would make more sense to check the validation in the Question instead of Event. Would you mind posting the Question model and update controller?

Comment: no problem. by update controller do you mean the questions controller?

Comment: Yes Question, my bad. sorry Im tired ><

Comment: damn still getting blanks

Comment: Hmm.. I may have to revisit this tomorrow. I would suggest taking a break! Happy hacking :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60428/discussion-between-cwmacken-and-dustin-falgout).

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution. A bit more explicit than the accepted answer IMHO.

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for : answers, 
  allow_destroy: true, 
  reject_if: -> { | question | [poll, foo, bar].any? &:blank? }
```